# How to check if project contains specific file for launch shortcuts

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Basically, I want to enable my [LaunchShortcuts](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_uishortcuts.htm) only when project has specific nature and contains **specific file**. Project's nature is not a problem. However, I can't find out how to check if project contains specific file. By far I have the following code in the `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<contextualLaunch>
    <enablement>
        <with variable="selection">
            <count value="1"/>
            <iterate>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                        value="my.project.nature" />
                </adapt> 
            </iterate>
        </with>
    </enablement>
</contextualLaunch>
```

Is it possible to check if a project contains a specific file ?

UPDATED:

@greg-449 gave me a great hint in the 1 comment below about using custom **org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters**. So, now my code looks like this:

```xml
.
. 
.
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
       id="my.tester"
       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"
       namespace="my.namespace"
       properties="myProperty"
       class="my.MyTester">
   </propertyTester>
</extension>
.
.
.
<contextualLaunch>
    <enablement>
        <with variable="selection">
            <count value="1"/>
            <iterate>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                     <and>
                        <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                                value="my.project.nature" />
                        <test property="my.namespace.myProperty"  
                                value="true"/>
                     </and> 
                </adapt> 
            </iterate>
        </with>
    </enablement>
</contextualLaunch>
```

Here is the code of **MyTester**:

```
public class MyTester extends PropertyTester {
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "myProperty";

@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] arg2, Object expectedValue) {
    if (property.equals(PROPERTY_NAME) && receiver instanceof IProject) {
        return FileUtil.containsSpecificFile((IProject) receiver);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work. While debugging MyTester.test() is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there anything that will search a project, but you can always write your own property tester to extend the `test` element using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is coupled with using **forcePluginActivation**. This defines that the Plug-in defining the property tester should be activated. If it is not activated, the property test cannot be performed.
So, the final version of the code should look smth. like this:

```xml
<contextualLaunch>
    <enablement>
        <with variable="selection">
            <count value="1"/>
            <iterate>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <and>
                       <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                            value="my.project.nature" />
                       <test property="my.namespace.myProperty"  
                            forcePluginActivation="true"/>
                   </and> 
              </adapt> 
           </iterate>
       </with>
    </enablement>
</contextualLaunch>
```

NOTE: Quoting the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_menus.html&anchor=e.test),

`forcePluginActivation - a flag indicating whether the plug-in contributing the property tester should be loaded if necessary. As such, this flag should be used judiciously, in order to avoid unnecessary plug-in activations. Most clients should avoid setting this flag to true. This flag is only honored if the evaluation context used to evaluate this expression allows plug-in activation. Otherwise the flag is ignored and no plug-in loading takes place.`