# Create dynamic launcher with “org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts”?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

I'm writting a custom launcher in my eclipse plugin. The purpose is to display options via the "Run As" and "Debug As" menu on the toolbar.

According to the answer from [How do I use "org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592493/how-do-i-use-org-eclipse-debug-ui-launchshortcuts) , I can add static options in "Run As" and "Debug As" menu.

How can I add dynamic options in theses menus. For example , according to the number of runtime server displayed in the server view , I know to display some options or not in the "Run As" and "Debug As" menu.

Comment: Before getting downvoted more for being helpful... :-P
OP: Can you please specifiy what you mean by "add dynamic options to the Launch Menu <Run/Debug as> ? What information does your user need to see in the Launch Menu beside the type of config which can be launched?

Comment: I need to earn a total of 15 reputation to downvote :) . I'm not the one who downvoted ur answer.  My user need to see the list of available server into the launch Menu <Run/Debug as>. I can't write a launchShortcut for each available server. The purpose is to automatically discover the list of available server and populate it in the launch Menu <Run/Debug Ad>

Comment: But you have implemented a custom launcher, which can handle to run/debug your servers, right?

Comment: Yes I've implemented a custom launcher to do it. But we've changed our strategy to provide a dynamic options because it's not possible with "org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts". As we are abled to auto discover the list of available server , we've created a preference page where the user can specific the default server to use for our custom launcher. So we don't need to display a dynamic options via "Run/Debug As"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enablement` configuration of your launch shortcut extension point declaration can be any valid [Eclipse core expression](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework). That also allows you to use [property testers](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework#Property_Testers), which are basically callbacks into your code to answer whether the launch config is enabled or not.

You can see an example implementation in [How to check if project contains specific file for launch shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688010/how-to-check-if-project-contains-specific-file-for-launch-shortcuts), which you can modify to answer the property test depending on your available servers.